# How to define a n variable function in fortran using array

Tags: function, variables, fortran, user-defined-functions

I actually want to solve an n variable hamilton's sets of equations. In fortran,to define a function, we, generally do the following.

```
function H(x,p) result(s)
real::x,p,s
s=x**2+p**2
end function H
```

Now, if I wish to solve an n variable hamilton's equation, I need to define an n variable H(x(i),p(i)) where i runs from 1 to n. Suppose p(i) are the variables and H is p(i)^2, summed over i from 1 to n.

What are the possible ways of defining a function with an array as input? It is not possible to write H(x1,x2....x100...) manuaaly each time.

Comment: Very quick, just write `real, dimension(:) :: x,p,s`

Comment: Can you please give an explicit example?

Comment: *In fortran,to define a function, we, generally do the following.*  .... *s=x^2+p^2*  not with those funny little hat symbols we don't.

Comment: @kvantour  perhaps `elemental` would be a better option ?  But it's difficult to tell.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If `H(x,p)` really is that simple, `elemental` was also my immediate thought. It takes a while to wrap your head around array functions, side effects, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module aa
  implicit none

  public :: H

contains
  function H(x,p) result(s)
    real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: x,p
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: s
    integer :: i, n

    n = size(x, 1)
    allocate(s(n))

    do i=1, n
       s(i) = x(i)**2 + p(i)**2
    enddo
  end function H
end module aa

program test
  use aa

  real, dimension(10) :: x, p
  real, dimension(:), allocatable :: s
  integer :: n

  x(:) = 1.
  p(:) = 1.

  n = size(x, 1)
  allocate(s(n))
  s(:) = 0.

  s = H(x,p)

  print*, s
end program test
```

Compiled and tested with GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

This is not really a *real case* program example because if you know the dimensions of `x` and `p`, you also know the dimensions of `s`, so you could have just defined it instead of allocating. But it can be used to generalize modules once there is no reference to any dimension in the module.

For this to work, you will notice that `s` must be *allocatable* and must have been allocated before calling the function.

Comment: Did you test this? See comment from  High Performance Mark with the question.

Comment: Fixed. I haven't compiled, was writing by heart because I've done this specific kind of function a lot, but I mixed the math part with other languages. Thanks!

Comment: Changed for a version which can be compiled out of the box.